# Function that return initials in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to define a function where a name is taken and its initials are returned in this format

```
assert initials('John Smith') == 'JS'
assert initials('Jason Ralph Jacobs') == 'JRJ'
```

I have this so far...

```
def initials(name: str):
    names = name.split()
    initials = (letter [0].upper() for letter in names)
    return(initials)
```

but i keep getting this message when i run it

```
initials('John Smith')<generator object initials.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000000000349F620>
```

Comment: add an explicit cast to `list` on intials like `return(list(initials))` or put `[]` brackets around your list comprehension instead of `()` then call `''.join(initials)` to return a string, not a list

Answer (score 1):

When you say, `initials = (letter [0].upper() for letter in names)` it evaluates to an iterator that will eventually yield all the initials. To explicitly make a string out of them, use `''.join(letter[0].upper() for letter in names)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that is because you are actually creating a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) with this syntax (in particular the parentheses):

```
(letter [0].upper() for letter in names)
```

This isn't incorrect either. If you iterate over what you return you will get your data.

However, if you are looking to simply get a list, then change your expression to:

```
[letter [0].upper() for letter in names]
```

Running your code as is and iterating over the result you get:

```
J
S
```

Now, seeing that you probably want to return that as a string, then you probably want to do something like this in your function:

If you want to use the list:

```
''.join([letter [0].upper() for letter in names])
```

Alternatively with the generator expression, same thing:

```
''.join((letter [0].upper() for letter in names))
```

The output would be:

```
JS
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
def initials(name):
    return ''.join(letter[0].upper() for letter in name.split())

assert initials('John Smith') == 'JS'
assert initials('Jason Ralph Jacobs') == 'JRJ'
```

What you were returning was a generator expression object, it must be iterated over in order for it to yield its results. This could be achieved by passing it to `list`.

Since you want a string rather than a list you can just use `join` to iterate over the generator.

Answer (score 0):

what i mean by my comment:

```
def initials(name: str):
    names = name.split()
    initials = ''.join(letter [0].upper() for letter in names)
    return(initials)
```

or:

```
def initials(name: str):
    names = name.split()
    initials = (letter [0].upper() for letter in names)
    return(''.join(initials))
```

or:

```
def initials(name: str):
    names = name.split()
    initials = [letter [0].upper() for letter in names]
    return(''.join(initials))
```

They all do the same thing.

The reason you are getting the input is that if you do a list comprehension with `()` brackets, you actually get a `generator object` rather than a list so when you print it, `repr()` is called on the generator and thats what it outputs.

you also need to take it one step further by then converting your generator/list back into a string, thats what `''.join` does